# How to set tick label precision on x axis

Tags: plotting

I want to plot some functions, let's say $24.30 x^{1.98} (1-x)^{2.06}$ and $9.1x^{3.1} (1-x)^{3.8}$ with the plot range for x to be from 10^-3 to 1. But, the graph generated doesn't show the ticks 10^-2, 10^-3 on x-axis.

```
Plot[
    {24.30 x^1.98 (1-x)^2.06,9.1x^3.1 (1-x)^3.8},
    {x, 10^-3, 1}
]
```

[image]

To be precise, I wanted a graph something like this given below

[image]

Comment: Please give copyable versions of your code. Did you try using `LogLinearPlot` instead of `Plot`?

Comment: Thank you for commenting. I have just tried with LogLinearPlot[{24.30 x^1.98 (1 - x)^2.06, 
  9.1 x^1.31 (1 - x)^3.80}, {x, 10^-3, 1}], the graph is ok but I wanted to display the ticks 10^-2 and 10^-3 which are not coming in the graph.

Comment: Welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. To add extra information to your question please [edit] the question, and leave the comments section only for coments.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`LogLinearPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLinearPlot) to get log scaling on the x-axis:

```
LogLinearPlot[
    {24.30 x^1.98 (1-x)^2.06,9.1x^3.1 (1-x)^3.8},
    {x, 10^-3, 1},
    PlotRange->All
]
```

[image]

If you only want power of 10 ticks, you could give an explicit [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks) option:

```
LogLinearPlot[
    {24.30 x^1.98 (1-x)^2.06,9.1x^3.1 (1-x)^3.8},
    {x, 10^-3, 1},
    PlotRange->All,
    Ticks->{Table[{10^n, Superscript[10,n]}, {n, -3, 0}],Automatic}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. You made my day. Since I am new to Mathematica it helps a lot.